# Error 1273 but my schema don't contain utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have developed an app in python with SQLAlchemy. My MySQL test database is in version 8.0 and my product database is in 5.7. I did the migration between the database and there is no error. But when I connect to the product database, I obtain the error "1273 (HY000): Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'".

However, my structure don't contain "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci". There is only "utf8mb4_general_ci".
I specify that this error occurs only when I connect to the product database.

Connection to database:

```python
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://user:***********@**********:3306/amatdb?charset=utf8mb4')
```

SQL example

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `alembic_version`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `alembic_version` (
  `version_num` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`version_num`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Fixed : 
Just add "&collation=utf8mb4_general_ci'"

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://user:***********@**********:3306/amatdb?charset=utf8mb4&collation=utf8mb4_general_ci')

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed : Just add "&collation=utf8mb4_general_ci'"

```python
engine=create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://user:***********@**********:3306/amatdbcharset=utf8mb4&collation=utf8mb4_general_ci')
```

Comment: can you explain why this happens?

Comment: @wanghaoming `mysql-connector-python` is made for MySQL8 - where `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` was introduced and made the default utf8mb4 collation. When connecting to a MySQL 5.x server, it still attemps to set this as the collation for the connection by default. Since MySQL 5.x doesn't know anything about `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`, an error is thrown.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Flask with Flask-SQLAlchemy, then the create_engine() method couldn't be accessed and changed easily (I didn't find any way to do that). Then the workaround is to change the connector version to 8.0.16

`mysql-connector-python==8.0.16`

The default collation `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` was set in the version `8.0.17`, so it works if you use any version before `8.0.17`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xampp maria db, just change the version of mysql connector to an older one, prior to version 8.0.17 that will work